# in Bigquery: Classify the weather for a day when two (or more) weather types (fx sun and rain) occurres on the same day

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with weather data as below. I wish to classify days as being either:

- "sunny" if the value is >0 (hours of sun),
- "rainy" if the value is >0 (mm precipitation)
- or both ("sun and rain") if there is >0 hours and 0> mm rain on the same day

| date | element | value | unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29.11.2021 | precipitation | 2,4 | mm |
| 29.11.2021 | sun | 0,2 | hours |
| 30.11.2021 | precipitation | 3,7 | mm |
| 30.11.2021 | sun | 4 | hours |
| 31.11.2021 | sun | 2 | hours |
| 31.11.2021 | precipitation | 0 | mm |

I've used CASE for classifying a day witn ONLY sun or ONLY rain like this:

```
case when element= 'sun' and value>0 then "sun" 
     when element= 'precipitation' and value>0 then "rain"
```

However, if a day has BOTH rain and sun I am not sure how to achieve this. I tried:

```
 case when element= 'precipitation' and value>0  
       and element= 'sun' and value>0 
 then "rain/sun" end as weather
```

but this will not give me any result, probably because i need to somehow partition by date (?). The outcome Im looking for is something like a classic weather report:

| date | element |
| --- | --- |
| 29.11.2021 | sun and rain |
| 30.11.2021 | sun and rain |
| 31.11.2021 | sun |

Answer (score 1):

You may change precipitation to say rain as you please, but here is the general idea of a solution using `string_agg`

```
with cte as

(select date, element
 from t
 group by date, element
 having sum(value) > 0)

select date, string_agg(element,' and ' order by element) as element
from cte
group by date;
```